# POST http://localhost:13799/HealthPotliWebService.asmx/CreateMarkers 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to post a JSON object to a asp.net webservice.

```
var markers = [{ "position": "128.3657142857143", "markerPosition": "7" },
               { "position": "235.1944023323615", "markerPosition": "19" },
               { "position": "42.5978231292517", "markerPosition": "-3" }];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservices/PodcastService.asmx/CreateMarkers",
    // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
    data: JSON.stringify({ Markers: markers }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

On the server-side, match your method's input parameters to the shape of the data you're passing in:

```
public class Marker
{
  public decimal position { get; set; }
  public int markerPosition { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public string CreateMarkers(List<Marker> Markers)
{
  return "Received " + Markers.Count + " markers.";
}
```

I get this error:

> POST http://localhost:13799/HealthPotliWebService.asmx/CreateMarkers
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I think you have to put [DataContract] and [DataMember] tags on the class an properties to de-serialize the input

Comment: Try removing the parameter once and hit the web service from js.

Comment: like this [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string CreateMarkers(List<Marker> Markers)
        {
            return "Received " + Markers.Count + " markers.";
        }

Comment: praveen , its working when i remove the parameter.